# How to edit the meta tags in particular post for open graph image and title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to edit the meta tags for particular post to my video site. To display open graph for social medias i have different images for that

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). There  you can setup meta data for each page and post.